# Something like Ruby on Rails increment_counter, but for DateTime.now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, race-condition

I'm looking for an ActiveRecord method that will set a specified DateTime field to "now", based on the database's idea of "now" at the moment of the update:

```
SQL: update object_type set time_stamp=NOW() where id = 37
```

rather than

```
Ruby: get DateTime.now
SQL: update object_type set time_stamp=% where id = 37
```

This sort of thing exists for simple counters (`ActiveRecord::CounterCache.increment_counter`)

Comment: What's wrong with `object_type.time_stamp = Time.now; object_type.save!`?

Comment: There are two problems with set & save. Both have to do with concurrent updates. One problem is that the two savers might have clock skew, so that the timestamp actually recorded thinks its from an earlier time. The other problem is latency: if the two savers' requests get scheduled by the DB out of order, again a wrong update could happen. DBs provide transactions to prevent this but they're (a) expensive, and (b) not available from Rails.

Comment: Note that User#touch(:field) is essentially the "object.field=Time.now; object.save!" code, so has the problems I just listed. But it is, at any rate, **neater** than any of these code snippets :-\

Comment: use an automatically updating timestamp column in your database http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: DB transactions are perfectly well available from Rails. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html